# Assigning Character to a player in multiplayer game

Tags: c, input, multiplayer

I am making a multiplayer game where the user needs to be prompted each turn to make a move. Each turn I am prompting 'Player X' where X is the player name.

How would I implement a second player 'O' to take every second turn. I am currently trying to use player->type, but need help updating type each turn.

```
struct player {
char type; // 'X' or 'O'
};

while(1){
player->type = 'X';

printf("%c", player->type);
play_game;

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. What have you tried so far? Show us some code.

Comment: Even with your code I don't understand what you want to do and what your problem is. And what is play_game ? A macro ?

Comment: You could store a char array of all the possible "types"... Like `char currentPlayer[2] = {'X', 'O'};`, then iterate through it to decide which player goes next. This way you can add more players in the future.

Comment: Alternatively I would initialise 2 `player` structs, put them in an array, then iterate over that instead.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question, i.e refrain from replacing it with nonsense.

Comment: I am voting to delete this nonsense, since OP seems wreak havoc.

Comment: @Matsmath No! The vandalizing edit is rolled back and now the question is back to whatever it was in the first place.

Comment: @Matsmath that's not a valid close reason. If you think something is nonsense, downvote it. If you think it's unclear, close vote accordingly. But as your comment stands, that's not a justifiable or appropriate reason.

Answer (score 1):

### Prerequisites:

Firstly, it sounds like you'd need to re-use the player struct since it's a 2 player game. To do this, you could use a `typedef` statement at the top of your file.

```
typedef struct {
    char type;
} player;
```

This enables you to create players whenever you want...

```
player p1;
player p2;
// you can say p1.type etc...
```

Then while the game is running you could simply switch between each player and perform operations on them however you like.

### Example usage:

```
#define NUM_PLAYERS 2

/* typedef statement goes here... */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    player[NUM_PLAYERS] players;
    players[0].type = 'X';
    players[1].type = 'O';

    int currentPlayerIndex = 0;

    while (1) {

         // Make a pointer the player you want
        player* currentPlayer = &(players[currentPlayerIndex]);

        doSomething(currentPlayer);

         // Move to the next player index (will wrap around to 0)
        currentPlayerIndex = (currentPlayerIndex + 1) % NUM_PLAYERS;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

This way you don't need to re-write logic for each new player. You can also add more players if you want.